# Why the AudioManager crash at RingerMode change?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

In my app, I already granted the permission for `PHONE_STATE` and it is detecting receiving/offhook/idle stats smoothly.

I need the mobile to ring if the incoming call is from respecified number even if the mobile is silent, so i'm changing the `AudioManager` status as below, but the app is crash once it is trying to change the ringermode!!

```
class PhoneStateReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {

        val state = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE)
        val incomingNumber = intent.getStringExtra(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER)

        val audio = context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager
        if (incomingNumber == "(650) 555-1212" && state == TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "Ringing ${audio.ringerMode}", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            if(audio.ringerMode == AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT)
            audio.apply {    // The app crash here!!
                ringerMode = AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL
                setStreamVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING,
                        audio.getStreamMaxVolume(AudioManager.STREAM_RING),
                        AudioManager.FLAG_ALLOW_RINGER_MODES or AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND)
            }
            val ring = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE)
            val r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(context, ring)
            r.play()
        }
        if (state == TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK) {
             audio.ringerMode = AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT
            Toast.makeText(context, "On Call ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
        if (state == TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "IDLE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }
}
```

And in `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

<receiver
    android:name=".broadcasts.PhoneStateReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

**UPDATE**

This is the Logcat error:

> 04-26 04:55:04.422 1406-2091/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying
>   enough data to HAL, expected position 1097356 , only wrote 1097280
>   04-26 04:55:04.434 5065-5065/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
>   04-26 04:55:04.446 5065-5065/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.hasan.ringer, PID: 5065
>       java.lang.SecurityException: Not allowed to change Do Not Disturb state
>           at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1942)
>           at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1865)
>           at android.media.IAudioService$Stub$Proxy.setRingerModeExternal(IAudioService.java:1161)
>           at android.media.AudioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.java:1099)
>           at com.example.hasan.ringer.MainActivity$onCreate$1.onClick(MainActivity.kt:20)
>           at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:6579)
>           at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:6556)
>           at android.view.View.access$3100(View.java:777)
>           at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:25660)
>           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:819)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6656)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:823)
>        Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
>           at com.android.server.audio.AudioService.setRingerModeExternal(AudioService.java:2333)
>           at android.media.IAudioService$Stub.onTransact(IAudioService.java:199)
>           at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:726) 04-26 04:55:04.453 1680-4664/system_process W/ActivityManager:   Force
>   finishing activity com.example.hasan.ringer/.MainActivity

Comment: You need to include the error logs in your question. Perhaps the `intent` parameter needs to be `Intent?` rather than `Intent`.

Comment: @Michael I added the error.

Comment: have you set `setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_NORMAL)` before setting `setStreamVolume` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, permission of `ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY` is required, in the manifest below line required:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

And the permission is granted from the `ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS` as below:

```
val notificationManager = getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted) {

        val intent = Intent(
                android.provider.Settings
                        .ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS)

        startActivity(intent)
}
```

Comment: above is solution for kotlin

Answer (score 0):

This is the java version of the answer from **Hasan** (see the code below) even if Kotlin do it better! :)

I found the answer, permission of `ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY` is required, in the manifest below line required:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NOTIFICATION_POLICY" />
```

And the permission is granted from the `ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS` as below:

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M && !notificationManager.isNotificationPolicyAccessGranted()) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_NOTIFICATION_POLICY_ACCESS_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```